# USGS geojson shakemap

Tags: geojson, feed

I am looking for someone with experience with working with USGS geojson shakemaps. 
I am trying to understand why some GeoJson feeds contain Shakemap as a product type associated with an earthquake but do not provide point coordinates for that Shakemap. 
Is it due to insufficient data available or is it an error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with geojson feeds and use point coordinates to produce a shake map you might find out that occasionally "download/cont_mi.json" file is missing from Shakemap contents. It is because some USGS contributing networks have not yet upgraded their software to produce this file.

The best option for now is to check whether this file exists before attempting to process.